# Maven annotation processing with maven-compiler-plugin

Tags: maven-2, annotations

I try to compile my code that contains annotations that generate source code. I use the `maven-compiler-plugin` and `build-helper-maven-plugin`. My POM is looking like that:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
                <generatedSourcesDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/apt</generatedSourcesDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>add-source</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sources>
                            <source>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/apt</source>
                        </sources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

When I run `mvn compile`, `${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/apt` is added as a source directory, and the generated sources are generated in the correct directory. But I get compiler errors because of missing references to the generated classes. It's like the generated source directory is not included in the compilation process.

I also try `apt-maven-plugin` which does not generate anything. And `maven-annotation-plugin` but it behaves as describe above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try with the latest version of maven compiler plugin (`2.3.2`)?

Also `build-helper-maven-plugin` is not required since it looks like you are using the `maven-compiler-plugin` itself to generate the sources from the annotation.

Comment: I had the same issue, it works fine with `2.3.2`, there is a "false error" about `missing symbol` definitions but it's just on the first pass to generate the *Metamodel*

Answer (score 1):

The release 2.0.7-SNAPSHOT of maven-annotation-plugin should solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

fwiw I just downgraded from 3.0 to 2.5.1 and fixed an issue I was seeing with APT processing not being executed after a few runs, using maven so just downgraded one version:

http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.apache.maven.plugins%22%20AND%20a%3A%22maven-compiler-plugin%22